# How can I delete a note written in Emacs howm-mode

Tags: emacs

I wrote a new note in Emacs `howm-mode`. Now I want to delete it, and I am not able to do so. **Should I delete the associated file on my system?** Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Emacs "directory editor", `dired`, though I think of it simply as a directory explorer.

Use `C-x d` to bring up a mini-buffer prompt for where to open `dired`.

I use `ido-mode` and a vertical presentation to make that mini-buffer easier to use, with these settings,

```
(ido-mode 1)
(setq ido-decorations '("\n-> " "" "\n   " "\n ..." "[" "]"
                        " [No match]" " [Matched]"
                        " [Not readable]" 
                        " [Too big]" " [Confirm]"))
(setq ido-default-buffer-method 'selected-window)
```

In `dired`, if you type `?`, it will show

```
d-elete, u-ndelete, x-punge, f-ind, o-ther window, R-ename, C-opy, h-elp
```

in the mini-buffer, so for instance, to delete the file under cursor, type `d x`.

Useful commands include `+` to create a new directory, or using `m` to mark several files, then `R` to move them all to a new directory, or `^` to jump to the containing directory. (I rarely use `^`, it's too far away from home row's `j`. More often I use `dired-x`'s more general `C-x C-j`, described below, or selecting the `..` you see in dired's buffer.) To create a file, simply use the global `C-x C-f` binding. More exotic commands would as usual be found in the menu-bar or manuals.

I would recommend the following settings to make `dired` easier to look at, in a minimal way,

```
(setq dired-details-hidden-string "")
(require 'dired-x)
(setq-default dired-omit-files-p t)
(setq dired-omit-files "^\\.$")

(when (locate-library "dired-details")
  (require 'dired-details)
  (dired-details-install))
```

You can use `(` and `)` to hide and reveal file information (`dired-details`), and `M-o` to toggle hiding of hidden files (`dired-x`).

`dired-x` also provides a `dired-jump` function, bound to `C-x C-j`, which will jump to the directory containing the current window's file.

The `when (locate-library...` statement is to prevent errors if you haven't installed `dired-details`, as it is not built-in to Emacs.

Comment: Cool... you're great... I just had to modify a small part as it was making error on my system. I replaced `(require "dired-x")` with `(require 'dired-x)` ... I am not sure if it should be corrected, or it just has to be done on my system.  Thanks again.

Comment: Perfect, you are right, I will edit. I was editing my version, in which I obsessively avoid requires, to try to speed up start up time. You can check out my `dired-load-hook` at https://github.com/bradyt/configs/blob/master/init-nav.el#L34.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, deleting the associated file from my system did delete the note.

Good enough.

I just wonder if there was a way to do it from within emacs/howm...

Comment: I've never used `howm`, but... are you familiar with Emacs `dired` mode? You can use `C-x d` to get there, and either mark to delete with `d` and execute with `x`, or use delete with `D`, and it will check if you are sure.